# Rückeschild, Polterschild: männlich oder sächlich?

Tags: article, homonym

Ich gehe davon aus dass beide männlich/maskulin sind: *der* Rückeschild, und *der* Polterschild. Eine Google-Suche bringt allerdings keine Klarheit, und der [Wikipediaartikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polterschild) hat beide Versionen im selben Artikel: 'der' und 'das' (maskulin und Neutrum)
Der Duden kennt die Wörter nicht, '[der Schild](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schild_Schutzwaffe_Schirm)' hat hier aber auch keine Bedeutung die direkt zu der von Rückeschilden/-ern (?) passt.

Ideen?

Comment: Nach *»der oder das«* zu fragen kann - vor allem für Menschen mit anderer Muttersprache als Deutsch - verwirrend sein, denn jedes sächliche Wort kann auch mit dem Artikel *der* verwendet werden, nämlich im Genitiv Plural (***das** Segel* aber *Das Flattern **der** Segel im Wind*). Besser ist es, direkt nach dem Geschlecht zu fragen, nicht nach einem Wort, das indirekt davon abhängt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast - Guter Hinweis, ich passe die Frage an.

Comment: Zwei Downvotes? Wer downvotet so eine Frage und warum? Manchmal weiß ich hier echt nicht.  Google-Suche zeigt auf den ersten Blick tatsächlich, dass das eigentlich "falsche" Neutrum im Gebrauch weit zu überwiegen scheint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Das Schild

Das Schild ist eine Tafel mit einer Aufschrift: Das Türschild, das Stoppschild, das Namensschild. Es kann auch ein Etikett sein: Das Preisschild auf einer Ware im Supermarkt.

Mehrzahl: die Schilder (Türschilder, Stoppschilder, Namensschilder, Preisschilder)

---

### Der Schild

Der Schild ist eine passive Verteidigungswaffe, die dazu verwendet wird, Angriffe abzuwehren. Der Schild besteht aus einer stabilen Platte (meist gewölbt). Auf der Rückseite hat der Schild eine Haltevorrichtung.

In der Science Fiction begegnet man oft einem Energieschild, der eine ähnliche Verteidigungs- und  Schutzwirkung hat.

Davon abgeleitet sind der Wappenschild (Bestandteil eines Wappens) und der panzerartige Schild der Schildkröte und von Krebsen und Insekten.

Ebenfalls davon abgeleitet ist der Räumschild bei Schneepflügen und ähnlichen Fahrzeugen, die mit einer festen Platte etwas wegschieben können. Unterarten von Räumschilden sind offenbar die in der Frage erwähnten Rücke- und Polterschilde.

Die Mehrzahl des männlichen Schildes sind die Schilde (Verteidigungsschilde, Energieschilde, Räumschilde, Rückeschilde und Polterschilde)

---

Bessere Wörterbücher als der Duden sind [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schild) und das [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Schild). In Wiktionary ist unter den 14 Bedeutungen des männlichen Schildes auch *»[9] Räumgerät eines Schneepflugs«* angeführt. Außerdem macht Wiktionary darauf aufmerksam, dass im norddeutschen Bereich die männliche Form nicht üblich ist und stattdessen die sächliche verwendet wird.
Das DWDS gibt fast immer fundierte Angaben zur Herkunft des Wortes.

Comment: DWDS ist ja super. Vielen Dank!

Answer (score 1):

Daraus, dass der Wikipedia-Artikel den Plural *Polterschilde* verwendet, ist zu schließen, dass *Polterschild* maskulin ist - der Plural von *das Schild* ist *die Schilder*. Diese Pluralbildung stimmt auch mit *die Räumschilde* bzw. *die Schneeschilde* im Artikel [Schneepflug](https://www.wikiwand.com/de/Schneepflug) überein.

Auch von der Bedeutung ist zu erwarten, dass *Polterschild* und *Rückeschild* von der maskulinen Version von *Schild* abgeleitet sind.

Dass der Wikipedia-Artikel an einer einzigen Stelle *das Rückeschild* schreibt, wäre demnach ein Fehler oder eine Variante.

Google-Suchen nach *Schneeschild*, *Rückeschild* und *Polterschild* legen nahe, dass auch die neutrale Variante verbreitet ist, die dann mit dem Plural *-schilder* gebildet wird. Da die Bedeutung *der Schild* und *das Schild* nah beieinanderliegen, wäre es nicht verwunderlich, wenn das Genus hier instabil wäre.